# Execute Python scripts using file association without new window

Tags: python, windows

Recent versions of Python include a `py.exe` launcher that will interpret Unixy shebang lines like `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and run the script appropriately. If you associate `.py` files with `py.exe` you can even run them directly from a shell (e.g. Powershell) like this:

```
./myscript.py
```

Unfortunately it still seems to run the script in a new window. Is there any way to make it output to the current shell *without* having to run `py myscript.py`?

Comment: I think I see the reason, and if so, this should only be a problem in PowerShell, not CMD. Apparently PowerShell will only select the code path that uses the current console if the file extension is in `PATHEXT`. If you add `.PY` to `PATHEXT`, it should use the current console, and you should be able to run it as `./myscript` without an extension.

Comment: Why they decided to change the semantics of `PATHEXT` in PowerShell from how it worked for many years in CMD is beyond me. CMD only uses `PATHEXT` when searching for files in a `PATH` search. It doesn't affect the way files execute.